# Не понимаю, как находить исключения с помощью отладчика в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, отладка, android-debug

Есть код, который гарантировано выбросит исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы подобные исключения отслеживал отладчик, для этого я перехожу по Run -> View Breakpoints и настраиваю отладчик следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После начинаю отладку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате я получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако я не понимаю, как с помощью этого окна найти выброшенное исключение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете в отладчике вызвать ваш метод руками нажам кнопку F2 и посмотреть его, но отладчик немного про другое.

Отладчик не помогает вам искать исключения. Выброшенное исключение вы можете посмотреть в стек трейсе. Отладчик нужен для того чтоб вы могли посмотреть состояние вашей программы (значения переменных, стек вызовов методов и др.) в разные моменты ее выполнения.

Отладка или debugging приложения — это процесс поиска и исправление ошибок или неправильного поведения кода.

Например: при получении ответа с сервера и его обработке внутри вашего приложения происходит непонятная ошибка и на экране выводится устаревшая информация вместо новой. Чтоб разобраться что происходит и найти ошибку мы можем при помощи отладки поставить выполнение программы на паузу в нужном нам месте и посмотреть содержимое наших объектов и переменных.

Именно для этого и нужен отладчик: приостанавливать выполнение кода в нужном месте и изучении состояния приложения.

Comment: Но я же сделал остановку по исключению, почему я не могу перейти к строке, в которой это исключение появилось

Comment: @НиколайСеменов, исключения не рождаются сами по себе - их генерирует код, к которому не правильно обратились. Соответственно точки останова на исключениях срабатывают в месте их выброса. Попасть вы туда не можете наверное потому, что это произошло в системном или библиотечном классе и у вас нет исходных кодов к ним. На нижнем скрине слева стек вызовов - поищите в нём упоминание вашего класса и метода - двойным кликом по нему вы должны попасть на строку в вашем коде, которая привела к этой ошибке. Но не факт что ваш вызов там есть, и что это поможет понять причину ошибки.

Comment: @woesss, упоминание метода нашёл, однако перейти к нему (с помощью щелчка) из окна отладки не получается

Comment: @woesss, я просто не очень понимаю сам принцип. Для чего делать точку останова на исключении, если этим потом нельзя воспользоваться в целях поиска места, где исключение было выброшено?

Comment: Место где выброшено исключение можно увидеть и без дебагера. Это есть в стек трейсе. А дебагер для того чтоб понять "Почему" выброшено исключение

Comment: Понял, спасибо)